# Java Lambda - How to insert a conditional within a complicated nested lamda

Tags: java, lambda

I have some existing code where I need to add a conditional. In the below, if the value of "at" is "FOOBAR", then instead of "accessTypeHit.right.getSortValues()" I need "accessTypeHit.right.getSourceAsString()". Otherwise, it should still be "accessTypeHit.right.getSortValues()".

Due to the complexity of the nested lambda, I am having difficulty figuring out how to address this. I would be grateful for any ideas. thanks.

```
public class DSHTAFunction implements Function<SearchHits, List<ImmutablePair<String, Set<AObject>>>> {
@Override
public List<ImmutablePair<String, Set<AObject>>> apply(@NonNull SearchHits searchHits) {


    return StreamSupport.stream(searchHits.spliterator(), false).map(searchHit -> {
                String id = searchHit.getFields().get(ID_FIELD).getValue();
                Set<AObject> AObjects = Sets.newHashSet();

                AObjects.addAll(ATM.INSTANCE.getTypes().stream()
                                             .flatMap(at -> {
                                                if (searchHit.getInnerHits() == null) {
                                                    return Stream.empty();
                                                }

                                                return Arrays.stream(searchHit.getInnerHits().getOrDefault(at.getIFName(), SearchHits.empty())
                                                                             .getHits()).map(h -> ImmutablePair.of(at, h));})

                                             .flatMap(accessTypeHit ->
                                                              Arrays.stream(accessTypeHit.right.getSortValues())
                                                                      .filter(sv -> sv != null)
                                                                      .map(sv -> new AObject(accessTypeHit.left, sv.toString())))
                                             .filter(AObject::isNonDefault).collect(Collectors.toSet()));


                return ImmutablePair.of(id, AObjects);
            }).collect(Collectors.toList());

}
```

Comment: `at` is the same as `accessTypeHit.left`, isn't it? Other remarks: 1. why do you collect to list and add the result to set, instead of collecting directly to set? 2. Improve code formatting, it will get easier on the eyes.

Comment: OMG what a mess. I would start with breaking this blob of code into more manageable pieces by moving each and every lambda into a (static) method.

Comment: @Lesiak what do you mean av? there is no av. I am afraid I would not know how to reformat correctly.

Comment: @TimothyClotworthy My bad - it was a typo, changed to `at`.

Comment: @Lesiak actually yes that turns out to be correct. at does end up being the same as accessTypeHit.left . However, I still would not know how to reformat to improve upon what you see above.

Comment: Than you can compare it with `FOOBAR` and pick the right value (ternary operator or statement lambda). But PLEASE, refactor it. Even extractMethod from your IDE for each part will be a huge improvement.

Comment: @Lesiak oh I see. yes I can do it locally there. thanks. This is code I am not supposed to refactor to much, in spite of how it looks, so I am likely to take the simple path. Sorry

Comment: I'm only trying to say that a decent IDE will do the work for you. https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/guide/tips/extract-method/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240691/discussion-between-timothy-clotworthy-and-lesiak).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extract every nested flatMap function into its own method. Then your work will become much simpler

```
public class DSHTAFunction implements Function<SearchHits, List<ImmutablePair<String, Set<AObject>>>> {

  @Override
  public List<ImmutablePair<String, Set<AObject>>> apply(@NonNull SearchHits searchHits) {
    return StreamSupport.stream(searchHits.spliterator(), false).map(this::hitsToPairs).collect(Collectors.toList());
  }

  private ImmutablePair<String, Set<AObject>> hitsToPairs(SearchHit searchHit) {
    String id = searchHit.getFields().get(ID_FIELD).getValue();
    Set<AObject> AObjects = ATM.INSTANCE.getTypes().stream()
        .flatMap(at -> accessTypeHits(searchHit, at))
        .flatMap(this::toAObject)
        .collect(Collectors.toSet());

    return ImmutablePair.of(id, AObjects);
  }

  private Stream<ImmutablePair<AccessType, Hit>> accessTypeHits(SearchHit searchHit, AccessType at) {
    if (searchHit.getInnerHits() == null) {
      return Stream.empty();
    }

    return Arrays.stream(searchHit.getInnerHits().getOrDefault(at.getIFName(), SearchHits.empty()).getHits())
        .map(h -> ImmutablePair.of(at, h));
  }

  private Stream<AObject> toAObject(ImmutablePair<AccessType, Hit> accessTypeHit) {
    return Arrays.stream(accessTypeHit.right.getSortValues())
        .filter(Objects::nonNull)
        .map(sv -> new AObject(accessTypeHit.left, sv.toString())))
        .filter(AObject::isNonDefault);
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks. This worked great for me. AccessTypeHit is not actually a class, but its of type ImmutablePair<AccessType, SearchHit>, and once I made that one chance from above, the code compiled. As you indicated, in this clearer organization, it was easier to get my original task accomplished. I will remember to always find ways to simplify these complex lambdas by pulling up methods, etc. Thanks you much. Very, very helpful!